# SQL Server Bug?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am writing a function to process some CSV data. This is what I have written so far...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FGetCommaSeperatedValues(@csv as text)
RETURNS @tblIds TABLE(id int,csvlength int) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @csvlength AS int
    --SET @csvlength = datalength(@csv);
    SET @csvlength = 7685
    DECLARE @currentIndex AS int
    SET @currentIndex = 0
        WHILE @currentIndex < @csvlength
            BEGIN
                --INSERT INTO @tblIds SELECT @currentIndex,@csvlength
                INSERT INTO @tblIds (id,csvlength) values (@currentIndex,@csvlength)
                SET @currentIndex = @currentIndex+1
            END
    RETURN
END
```

My issue is that when I execute the function, using the following command...

```
SELECT * FROM FGetCommaSeperatedValues('')
```

The table returned does not show the results that I expect.

Everything is fine until around row 3624 or so (as expected, id column increments by 1) 
Then the values increment erratically.

My colleague tested this code in SQL Server 2008 and everything works fine. This appears to be isolated to SQL server 2000.

Does anyone know of this bug, and/or it's resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to **gaurantee** sort order in SQL Server you **must** use the ORDER BY clause.

[ORDER BY CLAUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

Comment: You would be surprised how many people have been caught out by this one!